# XNA dropping frames

Tags: performance, xna, frames, frame-rate

I've read that to improve performance frames (out of the 60 fps) can be dropped to allow for updates which are consistent with time rather than slowing down the entire game. I presuem this just refers to draw rather than update/backbuffer...?

That is - skipping frame may cause more jerky motions but does not make the game impractical to play. Does any one have any tips on how to implement this and whether this is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

xna game class manage that in an automatic way if you set IsFixedTime to true.

From MSDN:

```
If IsFixedTimeStep is false, 
   Update and Draw will be called sequentially as often as possible. 
If IsFixedTimeStep is true, 
   Update will be called at the interval specified in TargetElapsedTime, 
   while Draw will continue to be called as often as possible. 
   If Draw is not called, IsRunningSlowly will be set to true.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.draw(v=XNAGameStudio.41).aspx

Comment: Thanks I've read through the documentation and assigning IsFixedTimeStep to true should resolve this automatically but when the game has high activity it still slows down!? 

Do I need to do anything like: if (Isrunningslow) {elapsedtime = slowervalue} ?

Comment: maybe you should look for other improvements in your code. Have you checked if you have too much garbage? it can slow down your game and it's a very common problem

Comment: yeh it's garbage related due to particles as per one of the other queries i had - I was planning one fixing that but also implementing something like this frame rate workaround in case it also occurs during unforescene scerios...